# Why does `send` fail with Ruby 2.0 refinement?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Why does this not work?

```
module StringRefinement
  refine String do
    def bar
      length
    end
  end
end

using StringRefinement
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".send(:bar)
#NoMethodError: undefined method 'bar' for "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":String
```

Can someone explain why `send` doesn't work here?  And is there a way to dynamically call methods defined in a refinement?  I can't seem to find a good, full explanation of how refinements work in Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Because it is experimental?

Comment: @oldergod Really?  I just tried it again by copying and pasting the above code directly into pry and received the exact same error.  I'm also using 2.0.0-p0.  Are you sure you're doing exactly what I posted?

Comment: @SeanMackesey you are right, my bad.

Comment: You know what you got to do http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-200/issues

Comment: This is big enough that there's no way the developers would have missed it.  I'm pretty sure it's by design, though I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Don't know the reason either but might be linked with this http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-200/repository/revisions/38279

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because [the specification](http://Bugs.Ruby-Lang.Org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/RefinementsSpec) says so:

> ## Indirect method accesses
>
> Any indirect method access such as `Kernel#send`, `Kernel#method`, and `Kernel#respond_to?` shall not honor refinements in the caller context during method lookup.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Jorg.  Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I am tempted to say "This is by design". But again *[it's quite possible this design is not entirely stable](http://www.hark.com/clips/smdzwjmydj-sir-its-quite-possible-this-asteroid-is-not-entirely-stable)*. For example, the `module` and `class` scoping feature has been [removed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/537297d1cbcd2ed97488774e67c4fc001282a658) just a few months ago.

At the moment even on Ruby HEAD the only way is to use the root of all evil:

```
eval "puts 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.bar" # => 26
```

But really, this is just for the lab, right ? Do not unchain such code, kitten would die.