# refinement using a previously defined refinement in the same file: possible?

Tags: ruby

Sadly, the below does not work. Time is not able to respond_to(:format_to_my_datetime). So my assumption is that refinements in the same file can't use each other. Instead where I define my ActiveSupport refinement, I would've needed within that file to use `using TimeFormatter` to refine Time in the context of that method.

But am I missing anything? Is there any way I can do this all in one file, besides just reimplementing format_to_my_datetime(timezone) on ActiveSupport?

```
module TimeFormatter
  include MyFormats

  refine String do
    def format_to_my_name
      self.gsub(MY_NAME_FORMAT,"")
    end
  end

  refine Time do
    def format_to_my_datetime(timezone)
      self.getlocal(timezone).strftime(MY_DATETIME_FORMAT)
    end
  end

  refine ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone do
    def method_missing(method, *args)
      if Time.respond_to?(method)
         self.to_time.send(:method, *args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: [Why does `send` fail with Ruby 2.0 refinement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263261/why-does-send-fail-with-ruby-2-0-refinement)

Turns out that indirect method access is [specifically revoked for Refinements](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/RefinementsSpec), which is a huge bummer to me:

> == Indirect method accesses
>
> Any indirect method access such as Kernel#send, Kernel#method, and
>   **Kernel#respond_to?** shall not honor refinements in the caller context
>   during method lookup.
>
> NOTE: This behavior will be changed in the future.
>
> =end